# I made a script using python that generates a html file. How can I dynamically change its content using data being retrieved by a web crawler

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I start my code by creating a new html file I'm using pycharm as my IDE
for simplicity purposes I'm going to skip to the body section of the new html document being created by the following code.

```
newHtmlFile = open('todaysNBAScores.html', 'w')
newHtmlFile.write("""<body><p>**How can I dynamically change the content of this paragraph ?**<p></body>""")

newHtmlFile.close()
```

Although I haven't created the crawler I just need a simple example of a string variable to replace the current information in the `<p></p>` tag.

Comment: String formatting? `'<p>{}</p>'.format(value)`

Comment: You must use lxml package.

Comment: Thank You Both @MalikBrahimi so would this work ? Ex: newContent = ('05-08-2015 Final NBA Score 109 - 107') | """<p>{}<p>""".format(newContent).

Comment: @BartLorenzo Is that a tuple or a string?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I would do it like this.

```
dynamicContent = "Foo Bar"
content = "<body><p>%s<p></body>" % (dynamicContent) 

with open('todaysNBAScores.html', 'w') as newHTMLFile:
    newHTMLFile.write(content)
    newHTMLFile.close()
```

The *.html file will contain

```
<body><p>Foo Bar<p></body>
```

Comment: That's exactly as a wrote in the comments above.

Comment: You don't know how happy I am Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
template = '<html><body><p>{}</p></body></html>'

with open('index.html') as html:
    html.write(template.format(newContent))
```

Comment: Thanks This is really simple but effective

Comment: Please mark as answer with the check mark to the side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python to dynamically generate HTML files there are a lot of options.  One good way is to use the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/) template engine.

You design an html **template** that has place holder variables in it, then you **render** it with the values you want filled in each time.

First install jinja2

```
pip install jinja2
```

You provide the structure of your html page as a template, with special `{{ }}` blocks that show where data should be filled in.

Then you render the template by providing a dictionary with Key/Value pairs to fill in the blocks specified.

```
import Template from jinja2

t = Template("<Title> {{ title }} </Title><body> {{ content }} </body>")
dict = {"title": "First page", "content": "This is the first page"}
t.render(dict)
```

the result is a new string with the values plugged in

```
u'<Title> First page </Title><body> This is the first page </body>'
```

you can render it again with different values for a different result

```
dict["title"] = "Second page"
dict["content"] = "This is a different page"
t.render(dict)
```

result:

```
u'<Title> Second page </Title><body> This is a different page </body>'
```

A templating engine like jinja2 can do a lot of complicated transformations on html easily, so if you are doing more than just replacing one string, it is probably worth investing the time to use something along these lines.

See the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#basics) for more examples.